# Problems With ViewDidLoad

Tags: objective-c

I want my sub view controller labeled "navView" to appear off screen when the app is started and animate in when a button is pressed. But when I launch the simulator the "navView" has already appeared.

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    draw1 = 0;

    navView.frame = CGRectMake(-568, 0, 320, 568);

    newsView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (IBAction)sideNav:(id)sender {

    if (draw1 == 0) {
        draw1 = 1;
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
        [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.0];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

        navView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568);
        newsView.frame = CGRectMake(1136, 0, 320, 568);

        [UIView commitAnimations];
    } else {
        draw1 = 0;
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
        [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.0];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

        navView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568);
        newsView.frame = CGRectMake(-500, 0, 320, 568);

        [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: In `viewDidLoad`, are you sure that  `navView` is not `nil`?

Answer (score 0):

Is navBar IBOutlet, created in storyboard/xib or do you create it programatically? 
If you added it in storyboard make sure you created connection to your view controller. Now it doesn't looks like that because in most scenario you access your outlet as self.navBar.

If you created it programatically in viewDidLoad replace line:

```
navView.frame = CGRectMake(-568, 0, 320, 568);
```

with:

```
YOURNAVBARCLASS *navView = [[YOURNAVBARCLASS alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-568, 0, 320, 568)];
[self.view addSubview:navView];
```

YOURNAVBARCLASS is class which navBar is created from.

If your navBar is subclass of UINavigationBar you should use

```
[navigationController setNavigationBarHidden: YES animated:YES]
```